# Start jobs in background from sh file in gitbash

Tags: bash, unix, sh, git-bash

I need to start a couple of processes locally in multiple `command-prompt` windows, to make it simple, I have written a shell script say `abc.sh` to run in `git-bash` which has below commands:

```
cd "<target_dir1>"
<my_command1> &>> output.log &
cd "<target_dir2>"
<my_command2> &>> output.log &
```

when I run these commands in git bash I get jobs running in the background, which can be seen using jobs and kill command, however when I run them through `abc.sh`, I get my processes running in the background, but the git-bash instance disowns them, now I can no longer see them using jobs.

how can I get them run through the `abc.sh` file and also able to see them in jobs list?

Comment: You cannot see them through `jobs` since you're not using the same bash process. However you can see them through `ps`

Comment: My processes are java runnables that I am running and in PS I just see few java processes running, how to identify them ?

Comment: can I provide a custom name for the process, so that I can refer it when I need t kill it?

Comment: Say you're running `java smurf.java &`, you can do this `ps aux | grep smurf.java`. When you said you saw few java processes, weren't you able to identify yours?

Comment: this one doesn't work @smarbar, I start my process with the command "java -jar abc.jar" inside the sh file and then when I do "ps aux | grep abc.jar" I get nothing.

Comment: IMO this means either the process has finished before you run `ps` or your script is not running what you're looking for

Comment: My process is a boot service, and I am able to access it.